# Is sr4-matrix too specific?

Tags: support, tags

I know that the Matrix differs from edition to edition of Shadowrun. It still feels quite redundant having a question tagged "shadowrun-sr4 sr4-matrix". Shouldn't all the matrix tags be merged? The question would be tagged "shadowrun-sr4 sr-matrix" or something similar, so the system is still identified.

Is it practical being so specific? Which case would be more common, someone looking for matrix questions without caring edition, or someone looking for specific matrix edition questions?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's too specific IMO. We don't have "dnd3-feats" and "dnd3-skills", you use dnd3 + spells. All sr4-matrix questions also have shadowrun-sr4 on them so we should synonym sr4-matrix to - hmm, matrix or sr-matrix.  I favor "matrix" because that's the common tag usage, again not dnd-skills or d20-combat or gurps-settings...

Comment: I suggested sr-matrix for avoiding confusion on other word usages, for instance if there were a "The Matrix" RPG.

Comment: I get it, but a) that conflict does not exist and b) it's an atypical use of a tag. We've had that come up before with a new game with the same name as an old one (star wars, doctor who) and newest guy has to distinguish.  So if a Matrix RPG came out, they'd get [matrix-rpg].

Comment: As you see fit. I was saying imagining other RPG games with something called "matrix". But I suppose it will be somewhat similar to SR's matrix anyway.

Comment: @Flamma Other RPGs have magic, but we can understand the difference between [[tag:gurps-4e]] [[tag:magic]] and [[tag:fate-core]] [[tag:magic]]. So if other RPGs come along sharing the name, they can use that tag too. An issue might arise when one comes along with an entirely different concept, also called a matrix, but we can handle that when we reach it.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs For some reason your comment for this answer didn't show up on mobile and I couldn't delete my answer on mobile either. Ok yes, adding [matrix] after a shadowrun specific tag would make sense. I was thinking of the matrix tag as itself and I didn't find any value but combined with a game, yes it make sense.